# Need help in understanding why for loop didn't iterate whole list, yet while did

Tags: function, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm just beginning Python and I wanted to write some functions based on an exercise, and then call these functions from another function, all to extract first letters from each word in a string.

At first I tried a **for** loop but it didn't iterate through the whole list of words; only halfway. But a **while** loop did. Yet when I had the **for** loop just iterate the list and print out each element it worked. I'm struggling to identify why and hope someone can help me understand.

```
def all_first_letters(sentence):
words = take_words_from_sentence(sentence)
while words != []:
    focal1 = first_word_in_list(words)
    litreacha = split_word_into_chars(focal1)
    litir = first_letter_popped(litreacha)
    add_to_list(litir)
```

This function works and takes a sentence, breaks it into a  list of words, pops off the first word, then pops of the first letter of that, appends the letter to a list and then repeats until I end up with a list of initials of each word.
But when I tried it first with a **for** loop;

```
def all_first_letters(sentence):
words = take_words_from_sentence(sentence)
for word in words:
    focal1 = first_word_in_list(words)
    litreacha = split_word_into_chars(focal1)
    litir = first_letter_popped(litreacha)
    add_to_list(litir)
```

It would never iterate through the whole sentence. If I gave it a sentence of three words I got two letters; if five I got three letters, and of ten words it returned five.

My puzzle is why the **for** loop doesn't go through each element of the list *words* yet the **while** loop does.

I hope there's enough information here to understand without giving every function.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. We might need some more information to help you. What is `take_words_from_sentence`? Is that indentation correct?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that the indentation got messed up when pasted. Both the `words` and `for` lines are four spaces indented. No indentation errors at all. The same with the `while` version.`take_word_from_sentence` is a function previously made which takes the string and uses split to break it into a list of words. As is the same with the others; all are functions declared that I call in `all_first_letters`
I didn't post the whole code as I though it might be better to keep the post shorter. As I said, it works with the 'while' loop, but not the `for`.

Comment: I worked out what I did wrong, and in hindsight not posting the functions called made it impossible for someone to help. `take_words_from_sentence()` made a list from the words in a sentence. `first_word_in_list()` popped the first word, which split_word_into_characters() made into a list I could again pop off the first letter. I see now that running a `for` loop on a list that was being popped messed it up, and the `while` didn't. I found a way to fix it using deepcopy, and another simpler way by dropping a function. Thanks to Alexander, and feel free to delete  the whole question.